# Generate XML with multiple objects

Tags: c#, xml

I have multiple classes of objects and am attempting to convert them to one xml document.

The first class is:

```
public class GameObject
{
// data members
public int squareID;
public int objectID;
public String objectDescription;
public String objectName;
}
```

The second is:

```
public class GameEvent
{
// data members
public int eventID;
public String eventDescription;
public int hasEventOccured;
}
```

The xml structure I am looking for is

```
<GAME>
    <EVENTS>
        <event>         
        </event>    
    <EVENTS>

<OBJECTS>
    <object>            
    </object>
<OBJECTS>
```

Comment: Can you show your desired xml file structure?

Comment: Why don't you create a wrapper class and serialize that into xml?

Comment: <GAME>
 <EVENTS>
  <event>
   <eventID>1</eventID>
   <eventDescription>Used rock</eventDescription>
   <hasEventOccured>0</hasEventOccured>
  </event> 
 <EVENTS>
 
 <OBJECTS>
  <object>
   <objectID>1</objectID>
   <objectDescription>A large safe with a number pad</objectDescription>
   <objectName>SAFE</objectName>
   <squareID>115</squareID>
  </object>
 <OBJECTS>
<GAME>

Comment: @jsomers89 please update the question: XML is even less readable in comments than blocks of code.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in a single expression, the parameters of the `XElement` constructor after its name are used to create children, and collections are expanded so a LINQ expression will create one child for each node (`XElement` creates a child element, `XAttribute` adds an attribute).

```
var content = new XElement("GAME",
                    new XElement("EVENTS",
                       from e in AllEvents
                       select new XElement("EVENT",
                              new XELement("eventID", e.eventId),
                              new XElement("eventDescription", e.eventDescription),
                              new XElement("hasEventOccured", e.hasEventOccured)
                       )
                    ),
                    new XElement("OBJECTS",
                       from obj in AllObjects
                       select new XElement("OBJECT",
                             // make content for a single object
                       )
                    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define another class like this:

```
[DataContract(Name ="GAME")]
public class Game
{
    [DataMember(Name = "OBJECTS")]
    List<GameObject> Objects { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "EVENTS")]
    List<GameEvent> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Then using a generic method like this you can instantiated a new `Game` and pass it this method:

```
public static void Serialize<T>(string path, T value)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = 
                 new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    System.Xml.XmlTextWriter writer = 
                 new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

    serializer.Serialize(writer, value);

    writer.Close();
}
```

If `DataContract` attribute is not availabe, don't forget to add reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization`.

Answer (score 0):

Create the structure of your class like below:
Create the structure of your class like below and the serialize the object of class by assigning value to its properties:

```
[XmlRoot("GAME")]
    public class Game
    {
        [XmlElement("EVENTS")]
        public Events Events { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("OBJECTS")]
        public GameObject GameObject { get; set; }
    }


    public class Events
    {
        [XmlElement("EVENTS")]
        public GameEvent Event;
    }

    public class Object
    {
        [XmlElement("object")]
        public GameObject GameObject;
    }
    public class GameEvent
    {
        [XmlElement("eventID")]
        public int eventID;

        [XmlElement("eventDescription")]
        public String eventDescription;

        [XmlElement("hasEventOccured")]
        public int hasEventOccured;
    }

    public class GameObject
    {
        [XmlElement("squareID")]
        public int squareID;

        [XmlElement("objectID")]
        public int objectID;

        [XmlElement("objectDescription")]
        public String objectDescription;

        [XmlElement("objectName")]
        public String objectName;
    }
```